# rgrass7: "no stars import yet"

Tags: r, grass-gis, rgrass7

I would like to read a raster layer from GRASS 7.8 into R 3.6.1 (on Ubuntu 18.04). Whenever I use the `readRAST` method I get a cryptic message that simply says "no stars import yet" [sic]. The console capture below exemplifies:

```
> library(rgrass7)
Loading required package: XML
GRASS GIS interface loaded with GRASS version: (GRASS not running)
> library(magrittr)
> library(stars)
Loading required package: abind
Loading required package: sf
Linking to GEOS 3.7.1, GDAL 2.4.2, PROJ 5.2.0
> 
> initGRASS(
+   gisBase = "/usr/lib/grass78" , 
+   home = tempdir(), 
+   gisDbase = "/home/duque004/GRASSDATA/",
+   location = "global_igh_local", 
+   mapset = "duque004",
+   override=TRUE)
gisdbase    /home/duque004/GRASSDATA/ 
location    global_igh_local 
mapset      duque004 
rows        61319 
columns     160300 
north       8600750 
south       -6729000 
west        -20037500 
east        20037500 
nsres       250 
ewres       250 
projection  NA 
> 
> r <- readRAST(c("bio_zones_02"), mapset = "BIOLOGY")
Error in .read_rast_non_plugin(vname = vname, NODATA = NODATA, driverFileExt = driverFileExt,  : 
  no stars import yet
>
```

What could be causing this? I have used similar code countless times with other combinations of GRASS and R, but never saw something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it is a bit too early for the `stats` package. `rgrass7` must be explicitly instructed to use the `sp` package instead. The head of the programme should look like:

```
library(rgrass7)
library(magrittr)
library(sp)

use_sp()
```

After that the code is the same.